# Transfer contents of text file into a 2d array

Tags: php

So I have a text file with this format

```
2
3
1 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 7
0 8 0 7 0 1 0 4 0
0 3 2 4 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 9 1 0 0
3 1 0 0 4 0 0 2 9
0 0 4 8 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 3 5 6 0
0 9 0 2 0 4 0 3 0
8 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 2
2
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

EDIT:

I have to store the first two lines, 2 and 3, into two separate variables. The rest of the grid I need to transfer into a 2d array (no keys). I have to anticipate that the the program can handle multiple grids (represented by the value in the first line). How can I do this? I keep finding functions that have to do with merging 2d arrays that have keys.

Is there a better/more efficient way than the way I do it?

```
<?php
    $lines = file("sudoku.in", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    $num_board = array_shift($lines);

    for ($k=0; $k<$num_board; $k++) {
        $size = array_shift($lines); //get size
        $size *= $size; //square size

        //get rid of whitespaces in grid
        for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
            $lines[$i] = explode(" ", $lines[$i]);
        }

        //transfer to 2d array "sudoku"
        for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
            for ($j=0; $j<$size; $j++) {
                $sudoku[$i][$j] = $lines[$i][$j];
            }
        }

        //print_grid
        for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
            for ($j=0; $j<$size; $j++) {
                echo $sudoku[$i][$j] . " ";
            }
            echo "<br>";
        }

        for ($i=$size; $i>0; $i--)
            array_shift($lines);

    }
?>
```

Comment: open file; read 1st line into var1 using fgets; read 2nd line into var2 using fgets; loop until feof using fgetcsv to read lines with a  space separator argument; close file

Comment: But a PHP array __always__ has keys, even if they're simply ascending numeric keys

Comment: Please see edit to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("Token.txt", "r");
$arr = array();
$vars = array();

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    if(strlen($line_of_text)==1)
    {
        $vars[]=$line_of_text;

    }
    else
    {
        $arr[][]=$line_of_text;
    }
}

print_r($vars); // you can access it as $vars[0], $vars[1]
print_r($arr); // This is the 2D array you wanted.
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: you're reading 1024 -1 bytes each time you're looping... considering the OP's example... I'd say `fgetc` might even be a better fit...

Comment: @Gannicus, `echo $vars[0];// will print 2 and $vars[1] will print 3` . They both are seperate variables. Also, your other data is assigned to the 2D array.

Comment: I have to parse multiple grids so I can't use eof in reading.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with "2d-array"? When you're storing lines without keys in an array this would be a 1d-array, at least in my understanding?

EDIT - extracts all single-digits into variables

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($fname);
$array = explode("\n", $buffer);

// walk the array and extract single digit entries
for ($i = 0, $limit = count($array), $varcount=1; $i < $limit; ++$i) {
    // this test could also be more specific, e.g. with preg_match
    if (strlen($array[$i]) == 1) {
        $var$varcount = array_slice($array, $i, 1);
        ++$varcount;
        --$limit;
        --$i;
    }
}
```

This will simply extract the single-digit lines from the array, putting them in variables `$var1` to `$var999`. The problem is that you don't have any information as to how many of these `$varX` are created.

Comment: Does this mean that every line containing only a single digit would start a new 2nd dimension?

Comment: No, I only need the 2d arrays for the grid(s), the single values I want to store into variables.